# Creating objects from input in textfile

Tags: java

I am freshening up my java skills by trying out some excercises that I found on mooc.fi. But I have got to a task that I don't really know how to solve in the most efficient way.

I have created a Recipe class:

```
public class Recipe {
    private String name;
    private int cookingTime;
    private ArrayList<String> ingredients;

    public Recipe(String name, int cookingTime, ArrayList<String> ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
        this.name = name;
        this.cookingTime = cookingTime;
    }
}
```

And I have a textfile that looks like this:

```
Pancake dough
60
milk
egg
flour
sugar
salt
butter

Meatballs
20
ground meat
egg
breadcrumbs
...
```

I started with an scanner to read the file, but that did not feel right. I have then used different methods to parse the file into a String that I was thinking I could split on " " into multiple arrays and also got stuck.
My latest attempt was to parse the file as a list and loop through it while keeping track of the index but it still feels like I am making it harder than it should be.

Can anyone give me any tips of how to solve this problem ?

Comment: If you want to be able to save information about a Class to a file, to store it or to transport it over network and you don't care about readability, read about the [Interface Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Comment: Are the Recipes always separeted by blank lines? What java version are you using?

Comment: yes, until the end of file. I am using java 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wish to keep the file format as is, first thing I would tackle would be making the file read process memory friendly. So instead of reading the entire file into memory then processing it, I would read it line by line as a stream then process it along the way.

Given the structure of your file, the point you create a new object is at "every empty line", so keep that in mind.

Next, your code should be elegant as much as it is efficient, so you would understand what's going on in there without troubling yourself.

Lastly, be it Scanner or some third party library, what you use to read files depends on your use case and codebase. For a pet project without too much dependency I would go with Scanner, if that is going to grow into a more mature project, I might consider using Apache Commons IO.

To summarize what I have in mind here's a snippet:

```
List<Recipe> myRecipes = new ArrayList<>();
RecipeBuilder recipeBuilder = new RecipeBuilder();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");


while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
  
  String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
  
  if(nextLine.isEmpty) {
     myRecipes.add(recipeBuilder.build());
     recipeBuilder.reset();
   
   } else {
     recipeBuilder.addLine(nextLine);
   }         
}
```

Here I added a `RecipeBuilder` class that maintains a String list internally.

`void addLine(String line)` method adds lines to the current list until one recipe is fully read from the file.

`Recipe build()` handles the parsing stage after every line for a recipe inserted into the builder. For a simple file as this one, you can safely assume that the first element of the list is the Recipe.name, second is Recipe.cookingTime, and the rest are ingredients. After building the object it returns a new instance for you to append to your Recipe list you defined outside of the loop.

`void reset()` method simply empties the internal list for a new recipe to be read and build as you continue to read the file.

This is of course my point of view, hope that helps you to better your solution.

Also, I excluded the error handling and edge cases just for the sake of brevity, you must never skip error handling, and consider unexpected scenarios in your code.